# Change Wall type in Revit Using API

Tags: c#, revit-api

I am new to Revit. I am trying to change the wall type in Revit from Basic wall to curtain wall using C# APIs. Manually in Revit we can easily do that from properties wall type drop down but with API I am not able to get clear idea how to proceed with. Can someone help me with the same. Thanks in advance.

I can't find any API to set wall type or any Build-In property which I can change to get required result.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [`WallType` property](https://www.revitapidocs.com/2023/0c0d155f-5b2c-c09f-d7d4-41a8600560eb.htm) on the `Wall` object.